# How can I get FTP response information about each command easily, instead of reading a full RFC 959?

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to write a perfectly standard FTP server.

My server received 'SYST' command. And 
I tried on sending the response message "remote system is Mac OS X.\r\n".
but FTP client does not work. 
FTP client is /usr/bin/ftp in Macintosh HD.

more badly,
there in no responses information about each command in the RFC 959??
since I use english as second language, it's very hard to read RFC 959.

Could someone give me some link with response information?

Here is related image.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/15ktF514CH4E00-Ab0QwPAaXRk6G4eIbDcsRJuhOyAuE/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RFC 959 specifies all you need to know, probably you misread the description, or don't send the result code at the beginning of the reply. On the page 49 there is a list of commands and possible reply codes.